# Dell Inspiron 3000 touch pad single and double tap stopped working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: touchpad, dell, inspiron

Single/double tap stopped working on my Dell laptop 3k series. I had shut the lid of laptop, and when I opened it, I found the touchpad had stopped working. I rebooted the machine by command line.

Afterwards, I found that the touchpad's single/double taps have stopped working, also two finger to right click is also not working, but strangely enough two finger scroll is working.

This laptop is dual boot between Win-10 and Ubuntu 16.04. So I rebooted into Windows and found no issue with the touchpad.

If I try to log in using another user id/guest id the touchpad works without any issue. Is there a way I can revert or bypass any settings related to touchpad to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just bought a Dell Inspiron two weeks ago.  I find that the double tap will occasionally (and inexplicably) stop working and all my efforts to tap using my mouse result in highlighted text or other annoying, unintended actions.  I searched for a fix and found nothing helpful.  Luckily, I stumbled on a quick and seemingly effective fix.
Right click on your screen and you will get a dropdown. 
Hit "Select All" and then double tap on your mouse pad area. That's it! Your mousepad should work again.

Comment: Hmm. Does this need to be done each time? If so, that counts as a workaround. If not, I guess it only happened once, so maybe it was a fluke.